# timer on sessionStorage stop on refresh

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer, session-storage

I am doing a timer that I store in a sessionStorage but if a refresh the page the timer stop! some help please

```
function time (secondes) {
    const temps = Date.now();
    const apres = temps + secondes * 1000;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((apres - Date.now()) / 1000)
        if (secondsLeft < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            sessionStorage.clear();
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('Timer') === null) {
                $(".reservation").css("display", "none");
            }
            return;
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("Timer", secondsLeft)
    }, 1000);
}
```

the getItem("timer") here is just to check if the timer is over, I am using this Timer item in another method

thx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sounds like you need to turn this the other way around - save the start/stop time to local storage, and get you function to check it.

Comment: Sessionstorage persist even on page load. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: sessionStorage will not be persisted if the page is refreshed @arjun sure about that?

Comment: @M14 I try to show a div with some data and time left before clear the div. only in session not in local

Comment: My bad, sessionStorage will be persist page refresh.

Comment: what you can do is, after Timer becomes 0, call another method which will hide the div. And if the Timer is not zero, show the current value of timer in the Div (or span inside this div).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionStorage persist even if the page reloads. Read this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

What you should do is, after you refresh the page, get the value of Timer again from SessionStorage and then again call the method.

```
function time (secondes) {
const temps = Date.now();
const apres = temps + secondes * 1000;
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const secondsLeft = Math.round((apres - Date.now()) / 1000)
    if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        sessionStorage.clear();
        //you dont need below if condition as secondsLeft is already 0. Commented if condition.
        //if (sessionStorage.getItem('Timer') === null) {
            $(".reservation").css("display", "none");
        //}
        return;
    }
    else{
      //update the div content and show the current timer value in the div or in the span inside the div. (write a separate function for this).
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("Timer", secondsLeft)
    }, 1000);
}

//Method to call after page load:
function startTimerOnPageLoad(){
     var x = parseInt( sessionStorage.getItem('Timer'));
     //put a check, Timer is present in sessionStorage and x is not undefined. I've not added it here purposely.
     time(x);
}
```

Comment: I modified your code slightly, the first if condition, i made is <= 0 .... and i removed the inner if condition because you already cleared Timer from sessionStorage so no need to check the value again.